# Как оставить только цифры, без букв?

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
test-test-example-demo-1a-3321-0-3555-0
```

Мне нужно удалить все кроме цифр, но чтобы 1a тоже удалилось, так как по с этой цифрой стоит символ отличный от -

Я делал так:

```
preg_replace('/[^\d-]/', '', $str);
```

Но в итоге я получаю:

```
1-3321-0-3555-0
```

А нужно получить:

```
3321-0-3555-0
```

Кол-во слов в строке всегда разное.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: кажется, написать решение с `explode` по `-` и фильтрацией чисел было бы быстрее, чем писать данный пост

Comment: `implode("-", preg_grep('/^\d+$/',  explode('-', $str)))`

Comment: Нужно уточнить какие подстроки должны удалиться: только из цифр, одна цифра одна буква, содержащие хотя бы одну цифру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одну строку регуляркой *(если нужно именно регуляркой)*:

```
$text = 'test-test-example-demo-1a-3321-0-3555-0';

echo preg_replace('~^.*?((?:\d+-)+\d+).*?$~', '$1', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$str  = 'test-test-example-demo-1a-3321-0-3555-0-';
$str  = preg_replace('/[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]/', '', $str); //удаляем все цифры после которых есть буквы
$str  = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z][0-9]*/', '', $str); //удаляем все буквы и цифры после них, если они имеются
$str  = preg_replace('/-(?=-)/', '', $str);//удаляем все оставшиеся парные '-'
$str  = preg_replace('/^-/', '', $str );//удаляем '-' в начале строки
$str  = preg_replace('/-$/', '', $str );//удаляем '-' в конце строки
echo $str; //можно конечно все регулярные выражения собрать в одну строку, но мне проще так
```

Comment: Что за велосипед

Comment: не велосипед, а постепенное объяснение человеку. я могу собрать это всё в одну строку, но так будет понятнее, что вообще происходит. и если у него возникнет непредвиденная ситуация или изменится формат исходной строки, то можно будет просто подогнать регулярное выражение, опираясь на мой пример. я понимаю, что через explode будет намного проще, но регулярные выражения тоже имеют место быть

Comment: во-первых, можно не вызывать каждый раз функцию передавая массив с паттернами (пример: https://3v4l.org/2lQnN). Во-вторых удалить парные дефисы можно так `/\-+/`. В третьих, чтобы убрать по краям дефисы, лучше использовать функцию `trim($str, '-')`.

Comment: можно вообще привести всё выражение в одну строку. я постарался объяснить как можно понятнее на мой взгляд.

Comment: The art of being alive, из-за низкой репутации не могу ответить вам в комментарии под вопросом. взгляните что происходит с вашими примерами, в случае изменения первой половины текста. https://3v4l.org/CnHSX https://3v4l.org/t0NAR вы даете человеку рыбу вместо удочки

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение у меня получилось без регулярки:

```
$string = 'test-test-example-demo-1a-3321-0-3555-0';


$array = explode('-', $string);

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(!is_numeric($value)){
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}

print_r(implode('-', $array));
```

Результат: `3321-0-3555-0`

Comment: Весь цикл можно заменить на более элегентное решение: `$array = array_filter(explode('-', $string), 'is_numeric');`